# Does flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 support the max-width attribute of the img?

Tags: css, image, pdf, attributes, flying-saucer

I added an attribute `max-width` to the `img` tag.

```css
.half-img {
    max-width: 283px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-top">
            <div class="number">1.</div>
            ae913d52-c459-48a2-b6b4-4e5a7b67f02a
        </td>
        <td class="table-top">
            <div class="number">2.</div>
            <img class="half-img" src="xxx.jpg" alt=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="number">3.</div>
            test text
        </td>
        <td class="table-last"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

At this time, it works normally in the **browser**.

[image: It works normally as a web document]

However, if I use **flying-saucer-pdf-itext5** to generate a pdf file, the image cannot be scaled and displays the original size. The image jumped out of my pdf border.

[image: it doesn't work when converted to a PDF]

Each of my images is a different size, so I can't use the `width` attribute to achieve that.

I would like to know how to fix it, or is there any other way to achieve a similar result.

My flying-saucer-pdf-itext5 version is 9.3.1.

Comment: Please format your question and images correctly, including a description for the image. Did you try specifying the max-with in the element inline style attribute?

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't work. I have now replaced itext7 and pdf2html.

Comment: The only way I could find was to specify the width and height explicitly in the <img> tag: `<img width="200" height="100" src="xxx.jpg" />`